# Refactor this block of routes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, refactoring, routes

I have to manually redirect a set of URLs, but seems like there's got to be a more efficient way (in terms of # of lines) than what I've currently go.

```
match "/articles/care" => redirect("/articles/category/care")
match "/articles/food-diet" => redirect("/articles/category/food-diet")
match "/articles/basics" => redirect("/articles/category/basics")
match "/articles/training" => redirect("/articles/category/training")
match "/articles/recipes" => redirect("/articles/category/recipes")
match "/articles/life" => redirect("/articles/category/life")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this out:

```
for category in %w{ care food-diet training recipes life }
  match "/articles/#{category}" => redirect("/articles/category/#{category}")
end
```